# What can bottle neck cURL's mult functions in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

Using cURL_multi is great for simultaneous connections, but what can limit the number of connections? I ask because when doing over 500 some of them seem to randomly fail to connect. I am doing HEAD requests with a timeout of 5, and increasing the timeout to 10 didn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 concurrent connections? That's a lot to ask for, the server is probably refusing to serve you.

Try setting a more reasonable limit, between 4-12 concurrent connections.

Comment: 500 to around 500 different servers, not 500 to the same server.

Comment: @AlexLunix: Still, it's probably too high for your OS configurations.

Comment: So the OS configuration is whats limiting it? Is there a way to change that on a windows server setup? I'm sure the hardware can handle it.

Comment: @AlexLunix: I can't be sure of it, but I highly suspect of that. I remember changing some setting in the regedit a couple years ago regarding that issue. I suggest you ask that question on SuperUser or ServerFault.